# Plaid api script to make global in next js app

Tags: reactjs

I have a plaid api connection that I want to establish in next js however i seem to be having trouble loading the script globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next/head to accomplish this. In your _app.js

```
<Head>
 <script src="url here"></script>
</Head>
```